# Install optional dependencies with tox

Tags: python, tox

I use [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to test a python project with the following basic config (`tox.ini`):

```
[tox]
envlist = py3
isolated_build = True

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
commands =
    pytest --cov {envsitepackagesdir}/foobar --cov-report xml --cov-report term
```

Unfortunately, the package's optional dependencies (as specified in `setup.cfg`) don't get installed; the corresponding line in raw pip would be

```
pip install .[all]
```

How to make tox install all optional dependencies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The supported way to do this is to use the `extras` key in your testenv

for example:

```
[testenv]
deps = -rrequirements-dev.txt
extras = typed
```

this will install `.[typed]` or `-e .[typed]` if `usedevelop = true`

---

disclaimer: I'm one of the tox maintainers

Comment: Saved my day!!!  You could add how to use multiple extras, though. Might help others like me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the dependencies of your `testenv` to

```
[testenv]
deps = 
    .[all]
    pytest
    pytest-cov
```

to simulate the behaviour of `pip install .[all]`