# How to define and invoke optional requirements with tox?

Tags: python, tox

I'm using tox for my project and I would like to install IPython as an optional requirement that is used only during development.

I'm using a `setup.cfg` file and I have defined the following testenv (simplified):

```py
[options]
extras_require =
    localdev = ipython

[tox:tox]
env_list = py311

[testenv:py311]
deps = <bunch of deps here>
extras = ipython
```

The testenv works perfectly, but I can't get the optional IPython install to work.

I have tried variations of the following:

```bash
$ tox -e 'py311[ipython]'  # the quotes are needed to escape square brackets
$ tox -e 'py311[localdev]'
$ tox -e py311 -e localdev
$ tox -e py311 -e '.[localdev]'
```

Everything fails with a similar error:

```py
...
ValueError: py311[localdev]
  py311[localdev]: FAIL code 2 (0.00 seconds)
  evaluation failed :( (0.05 seconds)
```

I have found this answer: [Install optional dependencies with tox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61878019/install-optional-dependencies-with-tox) but sadly I'm missing something and I can't get it to work.

I **know** that I don't know how everything works so no need to point that out ;)

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extras` is the keyword in `tox.ini` you need to use to install optional dependencies automatically.

So you need to have a section like

```
[testenv:py311]
deps = <bunch of deps here>
extras = localdev
```

And then just run `tox -e py311`.

Disclaimer: I am one of the tox maintainers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Perhaps I didn't explain the extent of my confusion :D 

If I run `tox -e py311` wouldn't that always install those extras?
and if not, _how_ do I tell tox that I want to install them?

That's why I was trying variations of `tox -e 'py311[localdev]'`

Sorry if they're super obvious questions but I just don't get it yet :(

Comment: To be clear: when I think "optional" I believe these extras are going to be installed only if I explicitly ask for them, otherwise they aren't installed. Am I wrong?

Comment: The `extras` statement tells toy to install the optional dependencies, so yes, it will always install them

Comment: You could create a new env called eg `localdev` and only use the `extras` key there.

Comment: For anyone coming later, what I wanted to do was to add more requirements to an existing virtual environment created with a given testenv. This doesn't seem to be supported, so instead I just created two different ones.